# Increase the update speed to PostgreSQL database via libpqxx

Tags: c++, postgresql, performance, database-connection, libpqxx

I have am trying to use libpqxx library to read and write into a postgreSQL database through C++.
The sample database I have is a 3 columns and about 16000 rows.

In my code, I use work.exec to transfer sql query and It took 30+sec to update all 16000 cells in 1 column.
I am not sure if I was not doing it correctly,or the write-in time depends on my hard drive speed?

Attached the sample code I used.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono> 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include <pqxx/pqxx>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
       //open connection to postgresql database
    pqxx::connection con("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=P@$$w0rd");
       //"pqxx::work" is an transaction type object in libpqxx, use to transfer SQL query or command
    pqxx::work wrk(con);
       //"pqxx:result" set containing data returned by a query or command
    pqxx::result res = wrk.exec("SELECT * FROM signal");

    for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
    {
       wrk.exec("UPDATE public.signal SET signalvalue = signalvalue + 1 WHERE indexid ="+to_string(i)+";");
    }

    wrk.commit();

    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << "Time taken by function: " << duration.count() << " microseconds" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you updating every single record in the table? If so, why not just do `UPDATE public.signal SET signalvalue = signalvalue + 1` without the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I use `signalvalue+1` as a test. Eventually each signal will be update every cycle and the update value will be different. I will need `WHERE` to ensure the update corresponding to the correct signal, or I need to make sure it updates sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance of your code could be improved by using a prepared statement.

From the libpqxx documentation

> If you have an SQL statement that you're going to execute many times in quick succession, it may be more efficient to prepare it once and reuse it. This saves the database backend the effort of parsing complex SQL and figuring out an efficient execution plan. Another nice side effect is that you don't need to worry about escaping parameters.

Your SQL statement would look like

`UPDATE public.signal SET signalvalue = signalvalue + 1 WHERE indexid = $1`

You can prepare this once, and then insert different values for $1 in your loop.

[The libpqxx documentation](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/a01480.html) has an example you can refer to.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the `UPDATE` statements in a single transaction. PostgreSQL is working in autocommit mode, so each of your `UPDATE`s is running in its own transaction. The 16000 flushes to the transaction log is what is killing you.

Start an explicit transaction with `START TRANSACTION` and end it with `COMMIT`.

This is a good idea apart from performance considerations because this way the data modifications are atomic, that is, all `UPDATE`s will be undone if any of them fails.

Comment: so what you mean is: instead of put `work.exec()` in the for loop, I should create a huge string, then use `work.exec()`?

Comment: No, you should execute `START TRANSACTION` on the database before you start the updates, and `COMMIT` afterwards.

Comment: I thought `pqxx::work wrk(con);` means start the transaction, and `wrk.commit();` means commit. Which object in libpqxx is refer to `START TRANSACTION`?

Comment: Hum, after reading the documentation it seems that you are right. To make sure, trace SQL on the database. If the updates really are that slow inside a transaction, either you have a lousy system or a gazillion indexes on the table.